# Dynamically remove angular.dart component?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Similar to this question of AngularJS - [Angular - How can I remove from the DOM an element I have used $compile on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797174/angular-how-can-i-remove-from-the-dom-an-element-i-have-used-compile-on)

How to remove a dynamically inserted angular.dart component from dom (esp. how to destroy the scope?)